# BLE Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create proof of concept to find nearby bluetooth low energy devices.
Here is my try:

```
 public async void StartScan()
        {

            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            adapter.Enable();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); // rode that this my help but didn't
            if (adapter == null) return;
            BluetoothLeScanner scanner = adapter.BluetoothLeScanner;
            scanner?.StartScan(_callback);
        }
```

The callback class:

```
 public class MyScanCallback : ScanCallback
    {
        public override void OnBatchScanResults(IList<ScanResult> results)
        {
            base.OnBatchScanResults(results);
        }

        public override void OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
        {
            base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);
        }

        public override void OnScanFailed(ScanFailure errorCode)
        {
            base.OnScanFailed(errorCode);
        }
    }
```

I`ve spent some time looking in Internet but each solutions gives me  always the same error. Everytime the code is executed it goes into OnScanFailed method with enum paramter ApplicationRegistrationFailed.

Does anyone faces the same issue?

PS. I have added required premissions.

Comment: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/issues/380

Comment: tried that solution - not working :(